# Swift Cannot assign through subscript: subscript is get only

Tags: swift

I am fairly new to the Swift syntax and am receiving this error with my code "Cannot assign through subscript: subscript is get only"

This is from the line: `friendDictionary[(friendUID as? String)!]  = ["name": friendsData!["name"]]`

Any advice on the correct way of doing it would be very helpful.

```
  func getFriendsUIDs() {

        if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil {

            print("failed to start graph request")
            return

        }else{
        }


        if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil {
        }

let parameters = ["fields": "name, id, picture"]
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me/friends", parameters: parameters).startWithCompletionHandler {
(NSURLConnection, result, requestError) in
let friendIds = result["id"] as? NSDictionary
let friendsData = friendIds!["data"] as? [NSDictionary]

        var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        ref.child("users").child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!).child("friendUIDs").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            self.FriendUIDs = NSArray()
            self.FriendUIDs = (snapshot.value as? NSArray)!
            print(self.FriendUIDs)
            var friendDictionary = NSDictionary()
            for friendUID in self.FriendUIDs {
                friendDictionary[(friendUID as? String)!]  = ["name": friendsData!["name"]]
            }

            self.fetchFriendFeed(friendDictionary)
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
}

}



func fetchFriendFeed(friendDictionary: NSDictionary) {


var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

for friendUID in FriendUIDs {

    ref.child("users").child(friendUID as! String).child("Agenda").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        print(snapshot)
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let friendPost = FriendPost()
            friendPost.picture = friendDictionary[friendUID as! String]? ["picture"] as? String
            friendPost.activity = dictionary["activity"] as? String
            friendPost.date = dictionary["date"] as? String
            friendPost.time = dictionary["time"] as? String
            friendPost.friendname = friendDictionary[friendUID as! String]?  ["name"] as? String
            self.friendPosts.append(friendPost)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
```

Comment: you can pass dictionary by reference from & operator. use inout with function parameter

Answer (score 18):

Nothing to do with Swift. You've elected to use Objective-C, in effect, by making `friendDictionary` an NSDictionary. NSDictionary is immutable; you can't assign into it or alter it in any way. That is simply a fact about Objective-C. The Swift `var` declaration makes no difference to this fact.

A better choice, since you are writing in Swift, would be to use a *Swift* dictionary, which is `[AnyHashable:Any]()` (in Swift 3). This will interchange with NSDictionary when you are talking to Objective-C, but it will give you a mutable dictionary because you (rightly) declared it with `var`.

Comment: Let me know, please, if that doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: I have updated my code so: var friendDictionary = [String: AnyObject]()
                 for friendUID in self.FriendUIDs {
               
                    friendDictionary[(friendUID as? String)!] = ["name": friendsData["name"]]
                  
I now get the error "Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal" when trying to set the name. What should i of done? Thanks

Comment: As a newbie i did what i thought you meant, instead of being funny about it why not just help me out and explain what you mean instead? i have set friendDictionary = [String: AnyObject](), which for me at looking what you said i thought was the right thing to do.

Comment: Really? You think when I say `[AnyHashable:Any]()` it's the same as `[String: AnyObject]()`? Is that because you're not using Swift 3?

Comment: Haha yes i did think that, like i say i'm a newbie. No i'm using swift 2.3

Comment: Okay, that's important to know. I don't think I'll be able to help with that. You might try using `NSMutableDictionary()` instead just to see if it gets you out of the blockage you're in.

Answer (score 13):

Have you tried using NSMutableDictionary? That solved the issue for me.

Comment: Doing this I then receive the error contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal. Any ideas where i could be going wrong? After being stuck on this for a while i have left it and carried on with other parts of my project but it would be good to understand what I could do to fix this.

Comment: Darren, I'm afraid I cannot help you directly. I may be a bit in over my head. However I got around it by changing my dictionary to `NSMutableDictionary` and setting the dictionary in my loop by doing this: `dict[key!] = value!` where key and value are both Strings.

Comment: I declared with `var dict: NSMutableDictionary` then initialised with `dict = [:]`. I'm just throwing information at you right now but I know how frustrating being in your position can be so I want to help as much as I can.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try and work with what you have suggested tomorrow and let you know how it goes, thanks once again!

Comment: Unfortunately still in the same boat and receiving the same error, just about giving up with this at the moment

Answer (score 2):

For those who get stuck here, another reason for this happens when you try to assign something that does not conform the actual dictionary, in my example i was doing something like this:

```swift
var dict = [Date : UUID]()
let randomUUID = UUID()

dict[randomUUID] = Date.now
```

whereas I meant to write `UUID : Date` but I was sleepy so i made a mistake, and Swift gave me a misleading error saying `subscript is get-only`. So this error also appears with type mismatch for **Swift 5.7**.