# How to replace specific elements in an array using a generic function?

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

My initial problem: I have an array of Bool, e.g., `var array = [true, true, false]`. I now want to replace all occurrences of `true` in the array with `false`.

Just calling `array.replace(true, with: false)` does not work, it throws the error: `Instance method 'replace(_:with:maxReplacements:)' requires that 'Bool' conform to 'Collection'`

So I thought, why not create my own extension which will do what I need? I decided to also go one step further and make it generic (oohhh fancy :0), and this is what I came up with:

```
extension Collection {
    mutating func replace<T>(_ toReplace: T, with replaceBy: T) {
        if self is [T] {
            for (index, el) in self.enumerated() {
                if el == toReplace { // ERROR: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Self.Element' and 'T'
                    self[index] = replaceBy // ERROR 1: No 'replaceBy' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'Self.Element' -- ERROR 2: No exact matches in call to subscript 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After checking out some similar questions, I have adapted my code like so, but it is still not working:

```
extension Collection where Self.Element: Equatable {
    mutating func replace(_ toReplace: Element, with replaceBy: Element) {
        for (index, el) in self.enumerated() {
            if el == toReplace {
                self[index] = replaceBy // ERROR (refers to "index"): Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Self.Index'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

--> When I then click on "fix" on the last error, the line turns into `self[index as! Self.Index] = replaceBy` but it throws another error: "Cannot assign through subscript: subscript is get-only" which according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74695380/15577843) might just mean that I have a type mismatch...

Since I haven't worked with generics much yet (especially not in Swift), I have no idea on how to get my code to work. Please can someone help me?

Comment: If you do `extension Array` instead, it works. It you still use `Collection`, then you can't use `self[index]`, you need to use `self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: index)] = replaceBy`, but then you'll get an error as it's a get only. Because collection have no "modify value at index", but `MutableCollection` has. So `extension MutableCollection` and `let index2 = self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: index)] = replaceBy` should work. There are plenty of subtilities since `Array`, `Sequence`, `Collection`, `MutableCollection` are "more or less the same but not really the same", it's tricky imho.

Comment: I replaced `Collection` with `Array` in my second code example and now it works, thank you!! The get only thing about Collection makes sense, idk why I didn't think of that. I agree, it's tricky, but luckily we have people on Stack Overflow like you who will point people like me into the right direction. :) Thanks again and have a great day!

Comment: You can also just use the original method and pass a collection of one element `array.replace(CollectionOfOne(true), with: CollectionOfOne(false))` or simply  `array.replace([true], with: [false])`

Answer (score 1):

`Collection` is by default not mutable, it doesn't have any `mutating` properties, so if you want to achieve your goal you need to extend `MutableCollection`. One approach would be to iterate through all indexes and replace the one that match the given value:

```swift
extension MutableCollection where Element: Equatable {
    mutating func replace(_ x: Element, by y: Element) {
        var index = startIndex
        while index < endIndex {
            if self[index] == x { self[index] = y }
            index = self.index(after:index)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```swift
var array = [true, true, false]
print("Original array:", array)
array.replace(true, by: false)
print("New array", array)
```

Output:

```
Original array: [true, true, false]
New array [false, false, false]
```

Comment: there is a mutating method called `formIndex(after:)` exactly for this purpose `formIndex(after: &index)`

Comment: Nice one, @LeoDabus!

Answer (score 0):

`Collection`s aren't guaranteed to be readable. Its subscript requirement is only defined as `subcript(index: Index) { get }`. For example `1...` is a `PartialRangeFrom<Int>`, but its elements can't be changed.

[`MutableCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mutablecollection) refines `Collection`, and has a `subscript { get set }` requirement.

There's one other really import catch: [`enumerated()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/Sequence/enumerated()) does *not* return indices. From the docs:

> Returns a sequence of pairs `(n, x)`, where `n` represents a consecutive integer starting at zero and `x` represents an element of the sequence.

They call the resulting integer *`offset`*, **and not `index`**, for exactly this reason. For some collections, you *can* use this offset as an index (e.g. for `Array`), **but not for most.** E.g. `ArraySlice` can have integer indexes that don't start from zero, and `String`/`Dictionary`/`Set` don't even use integers for their indexes.

To make this work correctly, you'll need to replace `self.enumerated()` with `zip(self.indices, self)`:

```swift
extension MutableCollection where Element: Equatable {
    mutating func replaceAll(_ toReplace: Element, with replacement: Element) {
        for (index, element) in zip(self.indices, self) {
            if (element == toReplace) {
                self[index] = replacement
            }
        }
    }
}

var array = [true, true, false]
array.replaceAll(true, with: false)
print(array) // => [false, false, false]
```

Funny enough, I wrote a little post on exactly this: [Proper Array Iteration](https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Proper%20Array%20Iteration.md). I think you might find it useful.

---

## Future

Recently, a lot of new ownership-related features have been added to Swift. One popular idea is to add a new `for inout` construct, which lets you get mutable references to the elements of a collection.

[If/when `for inout` is implemented](https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-introduce-for-borrow-and-for-inout-to-provide-non-copying-collection-iteration/62549), it'll give you a more efficient way to implement this, which doesn't require calling `self[index]` to set the value:

```swift
for inout element in self {
    if (element == toReplace) {
        element = replacement
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MutableCollection`.

And you can calculate the index within the collection using the offset from the `startIndex`:

```swift
extension MutableCollection where Element: Equatable {
    mutating func replace(_ toReplace: Element, with replaceBy: Element) {
        for (offset, value) in enumerated() where value == toReplace {
            let index = index(startIndex, offsetBy: offset)
            self[index] = replaceBy
        }
    }
}
```

Or, better, you can just use the `indices`, directly:

```swift
extension MutableCollection where Element: Equatable {
    mutating func replace(_ toReplace: Element, with replaceBy: Element) {
        for index in indices where self[index] == toReplace {
            self[index] = replaceBy
        }
    }
}
```

The key observations are:

- You need the mutable collection; and
- The first element of the tuple produced by `enumerated` is an offset from the `startIndex` of the collection, not the index itself. E.g., consider:

  ```swift
  let array = Array(100..<110)
  var arraySlice = array[4...]
  arraySlice.replace(106, with: 42)
  ```

  The original values in this array slice are obviously `104`, `105`, `106`, …, `109` and a `startIndex` is `4`. The offsets produced by `enumerated` are `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, and `5`, in succession. Thus the value of `106` will be found in the array slice with `enumerated` with an offset of `2` from the `startIndex` of `4`. But `indices` will return the indices in this slice, namely `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, and `9`, avoiding the need to calculate the index from the offset from the start index.

Comment: `index(startIndex, offsetBy: offset)` is potentially doing a linear search operation on every call (e.g. for `String`, linked lists, etc.), so I don't think it's worth even showing (and certainly not as the first example! :p)

Comment: Agreed. I only started with `index(startIndex, offsetBy: offset)` because Larme introduced the OP to that. I prefer `indices`, too.

Comment: I think it's good to mention that, but to highlight the issue with it (the potentially-non-constant time offsetting of the index), and emphasize the `indices` as the better approach

Comment: `indices` is indeed, I forgot about them as I didn't dig much more on the issue (that's why I didn't write an answer, but a comment). I wanted to show highlight the difference between index of a "list" as `Index` and `Int`, which might be confusing since `Array` has a Integer subscript that does it as most language do too.